# Build working error and some errors in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I skipped virtual display while installing because it was 800mb so I thought I will download it later. But I am unable to find the option to download and I think because of that following errors are occurring.
[image]

First: waiting for the build to finish is not opening from past half an hour

second: "URL is not registered" showing in the red text

When I clicked on hammer button another error occurs
here is the screenshot

[image]

this is the error

this is the closer look

[image]

Comment: I suggest cancelling the ongoing build, and clicking the hammer at the top to try again.

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened

Comment: I added screenshot have a look